# How to use JavaScript logical operator for object property?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Is there a way to use a [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for object properties? For example, can I do something like:

```
var myObj = {};
var prop = myObj.prop || 0;
```

Where `prop` gets set to 0 if `prop` isn't a property of myObj? But here,

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.prop = 2;
var prop = myObj.prop || 0;
```

`myObj.prop` is set to 2 because `prop` exists in this case.

Comment: Do you only want `prop` set to 0 if `myObj` 1) doesn't have a property of its own named `prop`, 2) doesn't have a property anywhere in its prototype chain named `prop` or 3) has a property named `prop` (either in the sense of #1 or #2) but it is falsey?

Comment: I want what's behind option #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use the ternary conditional operator for it:

```
var has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
var prop = has.call(myObj, 'prop') ? 0 : undefined;
```

It is not perfect (future references to `prop` will no longer be a `ReferenceError` in the event that `myObj` does not have a `prop` property), but there is no better way without using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
if (!has(...)) {
  let prop = 0;
  // Do things with `prop` here
}
// prop is still a ReferenceError outside of the if block
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var prop = myObj.hasOwnProperty('prop') ? myObj.prop : 0
```

Comment: Just FYI, if `myObj = Object.create(null)` this will break - don't make unguarded references to things on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @SeanVieira Lol, I think we are both taking something here for granted. When I run the current version of your code `var has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
var prop = has.call(myObj, 'prop') ? 0 : undefined;` I get `ReferenceError: myObj is not defined`. The OP did include `var myObj = {};` as the first line.

Comment: Matt, I left the `var myObj = /* whatever you want on this side */` out of my answer to focus on the solution I was suggesting, but if you add the variable, everything will work, even if you use `Object.create(null)` as the value of `myObj`.

Comment: @SeanVieira As did I leave out `var myObj = {};` since it's already in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. You can use `hasOwnProperty` method to check that object has property or not

```
 var myObj = {};
 var prop = myObj.hasOwnProperty('prop') || 0;
```

Comment: But that does set `prop` to the value of `myObj.prop` if it does exist.

Comment: If `var myObj = Object.create(null)` the next line will fail - best to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler varient would be to set the property in your fallback

```
var prop = myObject.prop || (myObject.prop = 0);
```